# Pdftk file merge: catenation is not picking up files in desired sequence

Tags: pdftk

I am merging all pdf files in a folder. Files are named as

```
Q1.pdf Q2.pdf Q3.pdf ........ Q30.pdf
```

Command I am using

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output all.pdf
```

But in the output file (all.pdf) merged sequence is appearing as

```
Q10.pdf Q11.pdf ....Q19.pdf Q1.pdf Q20.pdf....Q29.pdf Q2.pdf
```

The sequence I want is

```
Q1.pdf Q2.pdf ..... Q9.pdf Q10.0df Q11.pdf ...
```

What option should I add in pdftk command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there is no such option but you can simply rename files before concatenating:

```
find ./ -name Q\?.pdf | xargs -I  % sh -c 'name=`basename %`; newname=`echo $name | sed 's/Q/Q0/'`; mv $name $newname'
```

(I'm almost sure it could be done in a simpler way but I just can't find that way right now)

where:

find ./ -name Q\?.pdf - finds files that have name starting with Q character, followed by a single character and .pdf extension and prints them into standard output

xargs executes commands given after -c option on every filename printed by find commnad

basename gives you filename without path to it (no folder names like "./" if you have searched in current folder)

Comment: The output is 0Q1.pdf 0Q2.pdf..... What I want is Q01.pdf Q02.pdf...Any suggestion?